# Looking for list.count with better time runtime/time complexity

Tags: python, list, count

I'm looking for a function/way like `list.count()` (count the occurrences of a list element in a list), but with a better time complexity. Is there a way?

Comment: I'm curious: how do you suggest to implement it in less than O(n)?

Comment: What makes you think that the time complexity of `list.count` is suboptimal?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812468/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-python-lists-count-function

Comment: It's not possible to better than **O(n)** because every element in the list must be checked.