# efficient way to find cumulative count for the elements of a sublist in a list

Tags: python, list

To find the cumulative count for a list of elements in another list , I can loop through the list for each element of the sublist (via list.count) and sum them up. Is it possible to the same with a more efficient Pythonic way?

Example:

```
test_list = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5]
to_be_counted = [1,2]
result = 5 (1 two times, 2 three times)
```

Comment: why do you want to use `list.count` internal function? Time complexity of the O(n) according to this post [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44813154/5222075].  
So over all time complexity O(n*k), where n is number of elements in test_list, k is number of elements in to_be_counted.

Comment: E.g. `len([n for n in test_list if n in to_be_counted])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `map` and `sum`:

```
test_list = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5]
to_be_counted = [1, 2]
print(sum(map(test_list.count, to_be_counted)))
```