# Code Optimization By Not Using Nested For Loop - Hackerrank Sparse Arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I need help.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/three-month-preparation-kit-sparse-arrays/problem?h_l=interview&isFullScreen=true&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=preparation-kits&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=three-month-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=three-month-week-one

The link above is the question on hackerrank. I have solved the problem and I was allowed to do the next challenge but I don't think my solution is the most optimized. I really wanna know about the best possible approach.

[image]

My code / solution:

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    # Write your code here

    # strings = sorted(strings)
    # queries = sorted(queries)
    results = []

    LENGTH_Q = len(queries)
    LENGTH_S = len(strings)
    for i in range(LENGTH_Q):
        total = 0
        query = queries[i]
        for j in range(LENGTH_S):
            string = strings[j]
            if query == string:
                total += 1
        results.append(total)

    return results
```

I believe my solution results to quadratic complexity which is not good. Please show me or give me hints on how to think of a better solution to this problem.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I have a second version of my solution but still not sure if it is more efficient because I don't know how the function `[LIST].count()` works inside. Anyway, please take a look the 2nd version:

```
def matchingStrings2(strings, queries):
    results = []

    LENGTH_Q = len(queries)
    for i in range(LENGTH_Q):
        query = queries[i]
        results.append(strings.count(query))

    return results
```

Comment: To make it slightly more efficient you can create an array of tuples of all possible two-element combinations of two input lists using `itertools` module and then go through all the resulting tuples and do a set intersection of elements to see if one of the strings contains the other.

Comment: @pavel Thank you. I will consider that but currently it is kinda new concept for me. Could you take a look at my update. I added a 2nd version of my solution.

Comment: `list.count`  has a complexity of `O(n)` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44813154/7938503)) so its still quadratic in runtime complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the length of the queries list and using i as an index to reference each value, in python you could just do a for loop for the length of an iterable like this:

```
for query in queries:
```

Then instead of defining an empty list and appending counts in the for loop, you could use list comprehension like this:

```
results = [strings.count(query) for query in queries]
```

I've been watching [Raymond Hettinger](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go?t=2790) videos. He is the 'itertools guy'. [He's also on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424499/raymond-hettinger).

In the video he also talks about generator expressions. If we take out the square brackets from the above maybe it uses less memory? Probably doesn't matter with short input lists.

```
results = (strings.count(query) for query in queries)
return list(results)
```

I'm not sure if there are any good alternatives to .count() in this situation.